# According to current knowledge where should you store passwords on your server and how do you protect them?

Tags: php, mysql, password-protection

Given is a system of PHP and MySQL on a virtual server.

I want to save passwords there. Frequently you hear people speak about their system being hacked and credit card information being stolen.

According to current knowledge where should you store passwords on your server and how do you protect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing user passwords I recommend using [Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Essentially you have two tables

```
tblUser(userID, userPassword)

tblUserKey(userID, userKey)
```

store a hashed user password in `tblUser` and a hashed Key in `tblUserKey` table.
The user password is decrypted using the individual users hashed key.

This makes each password completely unique and would be much more difficult for a hacker to decrypt if they would get access to your tables.

[Salt Password Hashing Walk-through on a variety of platforms](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: Please elaborate this further. I created the two tables. So let's say I want to create the userpassword. How do I create it? I found salt to be dealt with differently at http://www.webmasterpro.de/coding/article/php-sicherheit-passwoerter-sicher-speichern.html. What is your approach exactly?

Comment: Shouldn't crypt() be sufficient?

Comment: @PeterFren the example you linked too looks fine.  I agree that the salt should be randomly generated.  I store my salts in another table for the added security of a potential hacker needing to have both tables in order to crack the passwords.

Comment: How do you use http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to know some basic details:

- Hackers can't access database's column name, so never name your
  password's column `password` or `pass`, use something nobody can guess
- To store some important/sensible data in your database like password or credit card numbers, you should use a one-way encrypt function, like `md5()` or `sha1()`, when an user store
  his password in the database, you hash it THEN store the encrypted
  data in your database, when your user want to login, you hash 
  again and then compare with the one you stored before, this way, even
  if a someone hack your database, he will only get some encrypted
  data, and won't ba able to decrypt because this is one-way crypting.
- Don't forget to puts a login, a password and access rights on your
  SQL server, default is `root:''` so if you got an interface like
  PhPmyadmin, anyone could just connect on it and access your databases
  data
- Hashed passwords aren't secure nowadays, so you might want to "salt"
  your hashed data, To salt a hash, just add some caracters before the
  hashed data, like `XYZ` for instance so even if your hashed string is
  cracked, the hacker will not be able to find the `XYZ` you put before
  it

Comment: Replace "encrypt" with the word "hash".

Comment: I got phpmyadmin on the server. When I login to my server via plesk I can access phpmyadmin without addition pw and username. when I connect to the db via php I use a pw and username. So is it protected or not?

Comment: Ask yourself: can someone who don't know anything about your server type an url and instant-access your phpmyadmin page ?

Comment: -1 because "hackers can't access database's column name" isn't necessarily true and because `md5` and `sha1` have been bad ways to hash passwords for a long time now. Also phpMyAdmin, in my experience, hasn't been available to the world.

Comment: A friend of mine read out my entire database, printed it out and showed it to me, just to prove that he could. It included column names. He was able to access it over a numeric id I was using to fetch various pages.